# Dynamically added attribute doesn't work in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I have a simple form with two input boxes of `number` type. When i try to add `max` attribute via directive, it seems to ignore it and doesn't validates although attribute is added on the dom element. **When i add it inline it works**.I referred this question [AngularJs can't read dynamically set attributes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14547425/angularjs-cant-read-dynamically-set-attributes) but that did'nt seemed to help me.New in angularJS and completely clueless.

Any help appreciated.

Edit: Updated fiddle
**Demo** http://jsfiddle.net/tNUNh/6/

Answer (score 2):

Didn't look furthuer, but one solution you have is to recompile the element everytime you change its max value.

Just change inject `$compile` (`module.directive('type', ['$compile', function ($compile) {`) and after `attr.$set('max', '100')` call `$compile(element)(scope)`.

This doesn't seem right, but I'd need to look further into `input` directive code to see if it exposes a way to change it without recompiling.

Comment: hey i updated the fiddle as you suggested and it is causing anomalies. Would you mind looking into this: http://jsfiddle.net/tNUNh/9/

Comment: Does any way to get the input directive and relink this element? like this: angular.modules('ng').directive('input').link(scope, element, attrs). the $compile(element)(scope) would be raise recursive error...

Comment: Ok, I got it. see also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13459705/dynamically-adding-angularjs-directives/18220339#18220339

Comment: @I_Debug_Everything I got it to run (see http://jsfiddle.net/tNUNh/12/).
You simply needed to put the $compile **inside** that "if" statement